# Spotfire: Joining two tables - alternative to outer join

Tags: join, spotfire

I need help efficiently joining two tables in Spotfire. The first table shows tasks executed by employees on certain dates, while the second table shows the role/function of employees which can change due to promotions. I want to add the role of the employee on that specific date to the first table. The most logical solution I can think of is an outer join and then filter out the irrelevant lines, but with both tables having roughly 1M rows, this creates a massive number of lines before filtering. Are there better alternatives?

Example:

| Task | Employee | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Steve | 01/01/2022 |
| B | Steve | 01/07/2022 |

| Employee | Role | Start date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | Engineer | 01/01/2021 |
| Steve | Team lead | 01/04/2022 |

Desired end result:

| Task | Employee | Date | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Steve | 01/01/2022 | Engineer |
| B | Steve | 01/07/2022 | Team lead |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*,
       ( SELECT role
         FROM t2
         WHERE t1.employee = t2.employee
           AND t1.date >= t2.startdate 
         ORDER BY t2.startdate DESC LIMIT 1 ) role
FROM t1
```

Comment: Thanks Akina, for SQL this works indeed. I hoped I could apply this to Spotfire as well, but unfortunately this doesn't work. Any other suggestions for Spotfire specifically? (I will change the title/description of the question.)

Comment: @AB123 You tag question with [mysql], so I provide solution for it. I have no solution for Spotfire because I don't use it. Check, maybe it can execute raw SQL queries? if so then you may use above solution until specific one will be found.